# How do I browse all shapes in Visio (2010)

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm not very familiar with the shapes that are available for me to use. Sometimes I'm looking for a shape but I don't know what it would be called so I can't search for it and I don't know which category it would be in. Please tell me there's some "browse all shapes" option that just shows a huge grid of available shapes and allows me to scroll through it looking for something I want to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This tool may help you: http://viziblr.com/news/2012/3/10/browsing-visio-2010-stencil-shapes-as-a-document.html

It will create an HTML document that shows all the shapes in one or more stencils. So now you can browse the shapes without having to open up all the stencils one by one.

Comment: The html files link http://1drv.ms/1dM6bPX doesn't work.

Comment: And the images on the viziblr website also don't exist, so I suggest this link https://web.archive.org/web/20190928195317/http://viziblr.com/news/2012/3/10/browsing-visio-2010-stencil-shapes-as-a-document.html

Comment: Also, does the tool work with VSSX files?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Unless you make an extensive My Shapes custom listing.  You are going to have to do some searching but it should not be that hard.  Once you have the type of document selected it will give a default setting of shapes to you use and then you simply need to browse over to More Shapes and try to search out what you want.  Give it a little thought and time and you SHOULD be able to figure it out without much trouble.  Worst come to worst, if you don't know what THEY call what you are looking for, Google it how you would say it and more than likely SOMEONE else thinks like you do and noted the term they used instead.

I am not saying this for certain but I am not seeing any way to do it myself.  Good luck if this does not do it for you.