# Finding Visio Shapes

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is there some way of printing out ALL Visio shapes - I used to manually do a screen shot of all the shapes and then print it out and bind it so I could flip through the pages and pick out shapes that I needed.  Was really handy when I didnt know the name of a shape I was looking for. This exercise is now way too time consuming and was hoping there was some sort of gallery that I could scroll through that had ALL the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

See this related SuprtUser question: [How do I browse all shapes in Visio (2010)](https://superuser.com/questions/367576/how-do-i-browse-all-shapes-in-visio-2010/399293#399293)

In summary, I wrote a tool that prints out all shapes for Visio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Visio PowerTools Addin.  It has the wonderful capability of Creating a Stencil Catalog.
Here's the link [Visio Power Tools](http://visioautomation.codeplex.com/releases/) There are versions for Visio 2007 and 2010.

Comment: When recommending products, please use the [following guidelines](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225).